# Spring, XA and WebSphere

Tags: spring, websphere, xa, transactionmanager

I am trying to get XA transactions working in a Spring v3 application inside WebSphere v7.

My App Context reads:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" 
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/MQConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="myDB" jndi-name="jdbc/myDB"/>

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

I'm referencing [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html) that says mix in the UOW txn manager and you'll be fine. But it doesn't work that way. Instead, in the following code, the message is destructively read and is **not** rolled back when an exception is thrown.

The transactional logic is (in scala):

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Array(classOf[Throwable]))
def processNextMessage(category: String) = {
  val maybeMessage = readNextMessage(category) // <- this is a destructive read

  for (message <- maybeMessage) {
    // this is temporary code for testing
    throw new RuntimeException("blaaaaaah")
    // end temporary code

    // sendToQueue(message, queue)
    // writeToMessageStore(message)
  }
}
```

Can anyone advise how I can use WebSphere's JTA transaction manager with Spring?

Comment: How is the connectionFactory used by the jmsTemplate configured?  Is the transactionManager property of the jmsTemplate set?

Comment: There's no transactionManager property on jmsTemplate. And I read that the annotation approach means no explicit injection is required.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would really like to see the code for `readNextMessage` as that may be the culprit.

Is the queue connection factory set up as an XA resource. You are trying to use JTA for transactions, so as far as I know you need to configure the message qcf accordingly.

You do not have to setup the `JmsTemplate` for transactions, as these are handled by the `QueueConnectionFactory`.

On a side note: if you are just dealing with mq, you can skip the UOW JTA provider and use transacted JMS sessions, which should work fine.